# Have one property define the types in another array property, using JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

Given this example JSON:

```
{
  "type": "number",
  "values": [ 34, 42, 99 ]
}
```

Is it possible to define JSON Schema that makes sure that the contents of 
the `values` array are of the type specified in another property (in this example `type`)?

Above `type` is saying that the array `values` can only contain integers (using the specifier "number").

Or specify that `values` contains strings:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "values": [ "hello", "world" ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you will have to write an `if/then` block for each type you want to support. Sorry I don't have time to write a proper answer with examples. Let me know if this information doesn't help much! =]

Comment: Did you need further help on this? If not, have you considered accepting one of the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the "items" keyword. If it has a single value then that value is the schema for every element of the array.

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": { "type: "string" }
}
```

Assuming you're using a draft4 schema like most people do, section 8.2.3.1 of [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00) states:

> 8.2.3.1.  If "items" is a schema

> If items is a schema, then the child instance must be valid against
> this schema, regardless of its index, and regardless of the value of
> "additionalItems".

Comment: iirc, the OP is asking if they can dynamically validate a field based on the value of another field.

Comment: What is your evidence for saying most people are using draft-4? I think that's false based on the questions we get on the JSON Schema slack on a daily basis.

Comment: @Relequestual you are correct when you say I was wanting to dynamically validate the contents of a collection from another field. I know that may not be possible, or a bit unorthodox, but I thought I'd still ask and be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @erwin-bolwidt Thank you for the response. Is it possible to somehow have the "items" say that the contents of the array can be either numbers or string, for example?

Comment: @Relequestual I'm sorry - I didn't think that this was a controversial statement. I've read this somewhere and I found it confirmed; for example the schemas on json.schemastore.org - 179 are draft-04, 6 are draft-06 and 11 are draft-07. And the popular validators for the JVM support draft4 only - one of the reasons for writing a new validator that supports draft 7.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt No problem. There are two Java libraries that are documented to support draft-7 that we know about on the site. Please feel free to add yours if it is ready. Libraries that only support draft-4 may seem more popular because they will be older. Some are likely abandonded. Sorry if I was a little abrupt. We are trying to encourage people to think latest draft first whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will have to write an `if/then` block for each type you want to support.

The Understanding JSON Schema has a section on `if/then/else`: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Here is an extract that explains how `if/then/else` works.

> For example, let’s say you wanted to write a schema to handle
>   addresses in the United States and Canada. These countries have
>   different postal code formats, and we want to select which format to
>   validate against based on the country. If the address is in the United
>   States, the postal_code field is a “zipcode”: five numeric digits
>   followed by an optional four digit suffix. If the address is in
>   Canada, the postal_code field is a six digit alphanumeric string where
>   letters and numbers alternate.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
  }
}
```

For each type you want to support, you would need to write `if/then` object, and wrap all of them in an `allOf`.

Comment: @diego-barros did this answer your question or do you need some additional help?